# Folder files do not copy

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am having problems copying certain files to my home directory on the file server.

I store my files locally in a folder and when I copy the folder to to my home directory on the file server sometimes it works and sometimes it does not work.

What I have noticed is that ~$ files are not able to be copied.  Why can I not copy them, I do not want to continuously go through my extensive directory structure and delete all of the ~$ files, I just want to copy the complete directory.

Why can I not copy my directory?

Thank-you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Windows guy.

Aren't ~$ files shadow files for when Office has a document open? I think they impose locks on the files that prevent transfers.

Otherwise, try zipping/tarring your directory, then move the tar/zip file to where you want it, then unpackage it.